# Oracle-Apex process for insert into two tables

Tags: sql, plsql, oracle-apex

I have dialog page, with items from two tables.

I want to fill v_row_table2.fk_id with the value that P23_ID(identity column) will get

I use process for insert:

```
-- all variables are declared

IF :P23_ID IS NULL THEN
--INSERT

v_row.active                      := :P23_ACTIVE;
v_row.date                        := :P23_DATE;
v_row.start_time                  := :P23_START_TIME;
v_row.current_time                := :P23_CURRENT_TIME;
v_row_table2.logdate              := :P23_LOGDATE;
v_row_table2.filename             := :P23_FILENAME;
v_row_table2.fk_id                -- 


v_id  := pck_table.fn_ins_table_name(table_row => v_row);
v_id2 := pck_table2.fn_ins_table_name(table_row => v_row_table2);
```

I try to add:

```
SELECT identity_name.nextval
INTO v_fk_id
FROM dual;
```

And add v_fk_id into code but, It didn't work.

Insert function:

```
FUNCTION fn_ins_table_name (
        table_row IN table2%rowtype
    ) RETURN table2.table_id%TYPE 
    IS
        v_table2_id table2.table_id%TYPE;
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO table2 VALUES table_row RETURNING 
        table_id INTO v_table2_id;  -- table_id is identity

        RETURN v_table2_id;
    END fn_ins_table_name;
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't really an apex issue, but a pure pl/sql question. Your question is: "how do i get the generated value of a column as result of an insert". You can use the "RETURNING INTO" clause for that. It returns the value of a column into a variable. Plenty of examples everywhere of this clause.

You have not provided the description of your function fn_ins_table_name but it should return the newly generated id for that row. Your code would then look like this:

```
IF :P23_ID IS NULL THEN
--INSERT

v_row.active                      := :P23_ACTIVE;
v_row.date                        := :P23_DATE;
v_row.start_time                  := :P23_START_TIME;
v_row.current_time                := :P23_CURRENT_TIME;

v_id  := pck_table.fn_ins_table_name(table_row => v_row);

v_row_table2.logdate              := :P23_LOGDATE;
v_row_table2.filename             := :P23_FILENAME;
v_row_table2.fk_id                := v_id; 

v_id2 := pck_table2.fn_ins_table_name(table_row => v_row_table2);
```

Comment: I add function in question. Can I do it without changing function?

Comment: ... did you try it ? That is the best way to know if it works. You're the developer, it is your code. Rely on your own observations to determine if your code is solid and works.

If that function is pck_table.fn_ins_table_name - can't tell because you have not mentioned the package name - then yes it should work.